# plugins extension not showing in chrome 45 higher

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I have chrome 42 before and when i download some plugins in chrome store i just enable NPAPI in about:flags then the downloaded plugin will appear on about:plugins. I need to enable the NPAPI for the downloaded plugin to appear on about:plugins.

Now I update my chrome to version 48 when i download plugins, it does not appear anymore to about:plugins, i also check the about:flags but there is no npapi anymore on higher versions.

Any ideas how to enable my newly downloaded plugins to about:plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [NPAPI deprecation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation), npapi support has been permanently removed from Chrome 45.

> In September 2015 (Chrome 45) we will remove the override and NPAPI support will be permanently removed from Chrome. Installed extensions that require NPAPI plugins will no longer be able to load those plugins.

Comment: ok tnx... so there are no other ways to run NPAPI plugins to chrome 45 higher?

Comment: @George  I suppose no.